# How to fix New Project empty list in Blend for Visual Studio 2012 RC?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, blend, blend-2012

I have just installed Visual Studio 2012 RC that come with Blend standalone version. When I start a new project the list is empty, there are no templates to choose from.

[image: New Project Blend]

Do you have any idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: same pb here. you know how to solve this ?

Comment: Please look at my answer at the bottom of this site. I described a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual studio 2012 update 2 introduce a new version of Blend, witch is working correctly (including new project creation) for silverlight 4, silverlight 5, windows 8 app and so on.

Answer (score 4):

With the upcoming update of visuals studio (update 2) support for Silverlight and WPF will return. I think this will work on Windows 7 too. You won't be able to build Windows Store apps though.

You can install the [CTP of the update](http://blendinsider.com/technical/announcing-visual-studio-2012-update-2-ctp-2013-01-30/) if you like.

If you don't want to update visual studio yet, you can install the [Blend + SketchFlow Preview for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30702)

Answer (score 3):

What version of Windows 8 are you running?  The most recently released version of Blend with VS2012 must be installed on Windows 8 Release Preview, http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/release-preview.

This release of Blend targets Metro style app development on Windows 8.

~Lori

Comment: well, it was bundled for some reason, I'd never install Blend with my conscious mind :)

Comment: @Lori Dirks Is this version specific for Metro style only then? I have installed on Windows 7 and I would expected to find at least template for WPF apps compatible with W7

Comment: What a clusterf**k! How do I author a project created in Visual Studio 2012 with Blend?

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft Answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappsuidesign/thread/679fb286-2c68-4fa3-9bce-e9fc74d52dea/) Looks like it isn't available for win7 but have to update to win8  "Unfortunately Blend is empty on Win7, no matter which version you installed. It will work when you upgrade OS to win8. Or you can use visual studio directly."

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, with the visual studio 2012 pro installed with the web-installer available on the MS website.

As i understand, blend for visual studio 2012 can be used only under windows 8 ?!
So why is it possible to install it under a windws 7 o_0
Feel really strange that we can't anymore edit silverlight 5 xaml under blend anymore except under windows 8...

Answer (score 0):

I have Win7 + VS 2012 Ultimate SP3 + Blend installed and the following is a very good way to work around this issue:

- Do **not** try to open Blend seperately or open new projects in Blend
- Instead insert your new XAML based user control in a VS 2012 project or solution (...where they will end up anyway...)
- Select the XAML file in the project explorer in VS 2012
- Go to the VS 2012 menu => View => "Open in Blend..."
- TADA: The XAML based control is opened in Blend and you can just normally work on it

By the way: I have another machine, without any VS 2012 service packs installed. On that machine opening and working with blend is no problem. It seems to be a VS 2012 service pack related problem.

Happy Coding!